# Angular: "checked" attribute of radio input not working as expected

Tags: angular

In the code shown below,

I am iterating over `deliveryMethods` which are displayed in the view as radio buttons. I intend to have the first radio button pre-selected.

I applied the following attribute:

```
[checked]="ndx==0"
```

where `ndx` is the index of each iteration. But none of the radio button is checked.

How do I dynamically pre-select the first radio button?

```
<div *ngFor="let dm of deliveryMethods; let ndx=index">
   <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="form-check-input f-s-1pt2" type="radio" 
             name="dm.name" 
             value="{{dm.name}}" 
             [(ngModel)]="item.item.deliveryMethod"
             (change)="filterProducts(item)"
             [checked]="ndx==0"
             class="radio-dimension"> 
             {{dm.label}}
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using ngModel, value, and checked bindings, all at the same time?

Comment: can you post a plunker for this? however you are not binding any value to the control . use `[value] = "dm.name"` to use property binding and then set `item.item.deliveryMethod` as the same value in typescript to have the radio button pre selected.

Comment: you can try with my code below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have removed the `[(ngModel)]` and use property binding with `[value]` to bind the value to the radio button control . The below code works for me

```
<div *ngFor="let dm of deliveryMethods; let ndx = index">
              <label class="form-check-label">
                    <input class="form-check-input f-s-1pt2" type="radio" 
                      name="dm.name" 
                      [value]="dm.name"
                      (change)="filterProducts(item)"
                      [checked]="ndx === 0"
                      class="radio-dimension"> 
                      {{dm.label}}
             </label> 
       </div>
```

Here is a working plunker 
https://plnkr.co/edit/6Ay2zr7Ow3csB5Pxdgdz?p=preview

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: @Niladri - What if I want to get the value of the checked radio button on template driven form submit ?

Comment: This solution is useless, if you need to get value from this form! If you use #accessor to get the value from this form, there is too hard to controll it if you have multiple form! So, you must use formControlName or [(ngModel)] to keep track the value!

Comment: @RuslanJackson It is useless when you have multiple forms, OP is not using multiple form so this is not useless in this context.

Comment: @Niladri I say is useless, not incorrect or not working! My opinion, is to use Angular guidelines, to keep track of the value, using reactive Forms or Template Driven Forms, not  with #accessors! Otherwise go to use jQuery :)

Comment: @RuslanJackson If I was OP , I would have used template driven form or reactive form. I was trying to provide a solution to the problem statement given(which may be a spaghetti code) but my goal was not to refactor. That is a whole different issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `[(ngModel)]` without removing it just use following syntax in `angular`

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1"
                                #is_public="ngModel" name="is_public" [(ngModel)]="updateGroupData.is_public" [value]="1">
```

Keep in mind to use `[value]` for data binding.

OR

Use this with `true` and `false`

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="flexRadioDefault2" #is_public="ngModel" name="is_public [(ngModel)]="groupFormData.is_public" [value]="false">
```

Keep in mind to use `[value]="true"` or `[value]="false"` for data binding.